# Magento2 how to extend wishlist_index_index.xml?

Tags: magento2, template, layout-update

In my theme directory, wishlist_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer.wishlist">
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Button" name="customer.profile" as="profile" template="customer/profile.phtml" cacheable="false" />
            <block class="Unis\Profile\Block\Customer\Wishlist" name="customer.profile2" as="profile2" template="customer/profile2.phtml" cacheable="false" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

in Magento_wishlit/templates/view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('profile'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('profile2'); ?>
```

but the childhtml profile2 didn't display;

the block class

```
Unis\Profile\Block\Customer\Wishlist extend Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist;
```

Comment: Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer doesn't exist, did you mean to extend Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist?

Comment: Yes, I extend \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist. Thanks for reminding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in layout,if template have not module name,default module is same as block.so

```
<block class="Unis\Profile\Block\Customer\Wishlist" name="customer.profile2" as="profile2" template="Unis_Profile::customer/profile2.phtml" cacheable="false" />
```